To what extent does the council of Nicea reflect the beliefs of the early church?
The council of Nicea was held in A.D. 325 a few hundred years after the early church. Yet it contained church leaders from all over, and it reached a wide consensus on a number of issues. Some of these decisions seem contradictory with Protestantism, specifically the seeming appeal to bishops and the church community as a final authority.
For example, the council refers to itself several times as "the great and holy Synod," implying that these decisions are binding to some extent, not just suggestions. It refers to penance, which Protestants typically don't practice.
It also heavily implies that church custom ought to be followed:

It has come to the knowledge of the holy and great Synod that, in some
districts and cities, the deacons administer the Eucharist to the
presbyters, whereas neither canon nor custom permits that they who
have no right to offer should give the Body of Christ to them that do
offer. And this also has been made known, that certain deacons now
touch the Eucharist even before the bishops.

They also state:

It is by all means proper that a bishop should be appointed by all the
bishops in the province

which seems to appeal to church consensus in a way that seems to contradict Protestant beliefs.
Together, the most clear implication seems to be that believers everywhere are bound to follow the teachings given by ecumenical councils or decisions made by a consensus of bishops. I suppose Protestants could argue that humans are capable of error and that these teachings were a modern invention, not something believed by the early church. But if that were the case, then why would bishops from all across the continent be able to agree on these declarations?
I'm open to arguments that large swaths of the church had fallen into error by AD 325, or that this contradicts things agreed on in the early church. But I'm not sure how to make that argument. On the one hand, there's a lot here that we don't see said by Ignatius or early writers. On the other hand, I don't see Ignatius contradicting what's written here, and a consensus by successors of the apostles could indicate that the apostles themselves did believe these things and passed them on as tradition.
Ignatius also writes:

Let no man do anything connected with the Church without the bishop...It is not lawful
without the bishop either to baptize or to celebrate a love-feast

That doesn't directly imply everything said at Nicea, but the similarity in what's said at Nicea and by Ignatius seems to strengthen the case that Nicea was based on tradition passed down from the apostles. Why would the tradition change so much and so broadly?

What is the purpose of the four references to "Protestant" and the [tag:protestantism] tag? The idea of Protestants didn't even exist until over a thousand years later.

@RayButterworth Protestants would consider themselves more in line with the early church and argue with some of the things Nicea said. That's why I'm mentioning them.
(Also, am I tagging correctly?)

The quote you have from Ignatius of Antioch was probably written in the early 2nd century, and was arguing in favour a strict episcopal hierarchy in a Church where some followed such a system and others a less hierarchical structure.  Saying baptism requires the bishop is stronger than modern practice.

If you read the canons of the first council Nicaea it should be clear that these are unlikely to be things that everybody did before the Council took place (otherwise why make a rule), but instead an agreement by the majority of the Council on what should be done from that time onwards.

@Henry In that case, wouldn't it imply a consensus that councils should be obeyed or believed by default? Calling themselves the the "great and holy Synod," and giving specific procedures for how bishops ought to be selected and for excommunication.

@ChristianMontgomery The councils you agree with are "great and holy" while the ones you disagree with are "robber councils" perhaps such as the Second Council of Ephesus and the Third Council of Sirmium and the Council of Hieria.  They all expected to be accepted and obeyed.

@henry One can consider a council holy while also considering higher councils to have more authority. I'm not sure I buy that any are infallible, but looking at this council specifically, it seems unlikely that all of these commands would be endorsed if there wasn't a consensus that councils had the authority to issue commands that ought to be followed by those under their church. And if said consensus didn't originate from the early church, why did the majority of attendants all believe it?

@henry You know, looking at the robber council, it does seem to be a case against infallibility. Saying "ecumenical councils are valid, but only under x, y, and z circumstances" seems a bit like retrofitting the rules for what makes a council infallible. But I still wonder about the Lutheran view, that these councils should be taken as authoritative but not necessarily infallible. As in, we should follow the commands as long as they don't explicitly contradict scripture.

Or there is the approach in Article 21 of the Church of England's 39 Articles, though this is drifting away from your question about bishops.  My point is just that the Councils were typically called to resolve disputes, and so their canons cannot be taken to represent universal practice at an earlier date.

@henry You make a compelling case. I'd be interested to see if any Catholic has an opposing view, but I don't see them appealing to Nicea much to make claims about the early church. That's not dissmissing you by any means, I'm inclined to agree with your view based on what you've said.

You accepting Eastern Orthodox Answers? Cause... I mean, we existed back then and I'm sure I could provide some detail... actually. more then some detail as I read the question again. You've pointed out many issues and yeah...

The statement and belief many have who argues against limiting Belief to those supported directly by Scripture;
John 21:24-25
"This is that disciple who giveth testimony of these things, and hath written these things; and we know that his testimony is true.
But there are also many other things which Jesus did; which, if they were written every one, the world itself, I think, would not be able to contain the books that should be written."
And the apostles that followed and had an intimacy of mind with Jesus lived on, with such knowledge passed to them and not presented in Scripture must be huge in volume and Relevance.
And as Jesus established His Church on earth through them to Evangelize and teach done through time until the ending of the world, we can justify Church Doctrines that are accepted and not specified in Scripture and not opposed in scripture. Such is the Holy Ghost directed filling-out of the Faith, as a full huge tree passes from the tender first shoot.
The Catholic Ministerium is all the defined Doctrines as well as those Believed for extended periods of time by most of the Body of Christ, as they are considered to be Moved by the Holy Ghost (such as Holy Mary as co-Redemptorist)
A Bishops through delegation to those Priests, Christian laity, those many others under his Scope (or region), including Protestants' Baptisms when properly done, he does Baptize all that receive proper Baptism.
Catholic Counsels that are accepted by most or all Catholics over long periods of time are considered 'verified' by the Holy Ghost, with Nicea, Trent, and Vatican I as the most well-known, and others not known by most that also were rejected, were not verified, We witness more recently in relation to Vatican II which contain at least two Heresies - and has been argued by many Traditional Catholics as the 'silent' Public announcement of the Usurpation of the Vatican, Papal Office, and much of Leadership, by Modernists that would and are building a false Church, a worldly or 'Ape' version of Her to the murder of countless number of soul so far - and so is Justly Doomed to fail over time.
Synods are functional and healthy as they make clear the Bishops' Faith related to some aspects of Doctrines, accepted worship methods and practices, new or expanded interpretations, and similar, and in Faith depends on Holy Ghost direction.
They may fail, as in Vatican II should, when members are in a state of moral sin, in the normal ways common, or if they accepted their Offices with the intent to Betray the Duties, Oaths, and so legally hold those offices but never received the Charismas, Graces, extra priorities of Holy Ghost attention, .., and are in mortal sin from then and forward.
.. this is now argued as the state of Pop Francis, and those that hold such positions are Sedeprivationists. Although formally Pope, lacks much that normally Graced by God, and in mortal sin, lacks a Living soul and has only the minimal Holy Ghost interactions.
I hope I touched-on the most significant aspects of this questions, if not please comment, if any with 50(50!) points, that is.

Trad. Catholic Mysteries and seeming Paradoxes are the Seeds of further Theological realizations of the Faith, and a source of Fruitful meditations for me and others. After Converting I found Apologetics using current scientific theories valuable, although not Doctrine; the different versions of the Passion when all are literal Truth, and John's quoted, argues MultiWord many versions of Jesus' many lives, and-or Jacob's Ladder lives as He goes to Hell. I invite such Apologetics in others - especially those that worship Science, as victims of Satanic imposed Block against Faith, and Salvation.

Sadly, it seems that - by my count - 3 Answers of (-1) score, out of 12 Answers to 12 Questions here has somehow blocked my ability to Answer questions. So, the moderators anti-Catholics, and GramerNazis will not have me to kick-around for a while.
